# this в структуре

Tags: c#

Зачем для инициализации свойства структуры через конструктор использовать this? Без :this()  будет ошибка при компиляции

```
struct T 
{
    public T(int u)
        : this()
    { 
        this.U = u;
    }

    public int U { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: вроде сообщение об ошибке вполне информативное - нельзя обращаться к полям, пока они **все** не проинициализированны.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нужно ли вызывать базовый конструктор структур?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/596630/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80)

Answer (score 5):

При определении автосвойства, в классе/структуре создается приватное поле, в котором и хранится значение. Свойство же представляет из себя всего две функции: `get` - для получения значения и `set` для установки.

Таким образом, без вызова конструктора по умолчанию (`:this()`) идет попытка вызвать функцию `set` для установки поля, а это запрещено, так как в структуре поля должны быть проиницилизированы до обращения к ним.

В случае же вызова конструктора по умолчанию - поле инициализируется в нем значением по умолчанию.