# Инициализация структур C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-faq

Почему в значимых типах C# необходимо инициализировать все поля, при наличии конструктора?

Например, следующий код не скомпилируется

```
struct AAA
{
    public int A;
    public string C;

    public AAA(int a)
    {
        A = a;
    }
}
```

> Поле ААА.С должно быть полностью определено до возврата управления в
>   вызывающий метод

Но если уберем конструктор, то все компилируется

```
struct AAA
{
    public int A;
    public string C;
}
```

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Нужно ли вызывать базовый конструктор структур?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/596630/186999)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Дело в том, что для структур, в отличие от классов, нету инициализации полей по умолчанию (ради эффективности). Если вы не определяете конструктор, то у вас есть конструктор по умолчанию, который инициализирует все поля нулевым значением (`default` соответствующего типа). Если вы определяете свой конструктор, то достаточно вызвать конструктор по умолчанию:

```
public AAA(int a) : this()
{
    A = a;
}
```

Без этого поле `C` инициализировано не было бы, и значение было бы не определено. Такие ситуации C#, в отличие от C++, не допускает.

Comment: а не было дубликата? мне кажется про структуры прям недавно еще было

Comment: @Grundy: Вроде не помню точного дубликата.

Comment: Ага, я уже пробежался, глянул. Там немного о другом вопросы :-)